# neo4j shell -creating edges from .csv

Tags: csv, neo4j

I am using comma separated value file to create nodes and edges in a Neo4j database.  The commands which create nodes run with no issue. The attempt to create edges fails with this error:

> Exception in thread "GC-Monitor" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC
>   overhead limit exceeded
>
> Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the
>   UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "GC-Monitor"

Further, in the output from the commands there was this:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ using periodic commit 400 load csv with headers from 'file://localhost/tmp/vm2set3.csv' as line match (u:VM {id: line.vm_id}),(s:VNIC  {id: line.set3_id}) create (u)-[:VNIC]->(s);
SystemException: Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
neo4j-sh (?)$
SystemException: Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
neo4j-sh (?)$ using periodic commit 400 load csv with headers from 'file://localhost/tmp/unix2switch.csv' as line match (u:UNIX {id: line.intf_id}),(s:switch  {id: line.set2a_id}) create (u)-[:cable]->(s);
SystemException: Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
neo4j-sh (?)$
```

My shell script is:

```
cat /home/ES2Neo/2.1/neo4j_commands.cql | /export/neo4j-community-2.1.4/bin/neo4j-shell -path /export/neo4j-community-2.1.4/data/graph.db > /tmp/na.out
```

The commands are like this:

```
load csv WITH HEADERS from 'file://localhost/tmp/intf.csv' AS line CREATE (:UNIX {id: line.id, MAC: line.MAC ,BIA: line.BIA ,host: line.host,name: line.name});
```

for nodes, and

```
using periodic commit 400 load csv with headers from 'file://localhost/tmp/unix2switch.csv' as line match (u:UNIX {id: line.intf_id}),(s:switch  {id: line.set2a_id}) create (u)-[:cable]->(s);
```

for edges.

The csv input files look like this:

```
"intf_id","set2a_id"
"100321","6724919"
"125850","6717849"
"158249","6081895"
"51329","5565380"
"57248","6680663"
"235196","6094139"
"229242","4800249"
"225630","6661742"
"183281","4760022"
```

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there something in Neo4j configuration I need to check? Thanks.

Comment: Did you get it resolved?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're running out of memory for loading the data into the database.

Take a look at [this blog post](http://jexp.de/blog/2014/06/load-csv-into-neo4j-quickly-and-successfully/) which goes into a number of details about how to load CSV data in successfully.

In particular, here's the key bit from the blog post you should pay attention to.

> The more memory you have the faster it will import your data.
>
> So make sure to edit conf/neo4j-wrapper.conf and set:

```
# Uncomment these lines to set specific initial and maximum
# heap size in MB.
wrapper.java.initmemory=4096
wrapper.java.maxmemory=4096
```

> In conf/neo4j.properties set:

```
# Default values for the low-level graph engine
neostore.nodestore.db.mapped_memory=50M
neostore.relationshipstore.db.mapped_memory=500M
neostore.propertystore.db.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.strings.mapped_memory=100M
neostore.propertystore.db.arrays.mapped_memory=0M
```